# How to implement a .jar SDK in React-Native?

Tags: sdk

I'm developing an application as an end-of-course assignment and I've been provided with the SDK in .jar .

So I went to android/app/build.gradle and inserted the following line:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'android/app/libs', include: ['*.aar', '*.jar']) // Line add
    ...


    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}
```

But then I don't know what to do, because when I call the SDK in my MuseSDK.java module as follows:

```
import com.headband.libmuse.Accelerometer;
import com.choosemuse.libmuse.AnnotationData;
```

and I get this:

Cannot resolve symbol 'libmuse'
Cannot resolve symbol 'choosemuse'

I called it this way because I have no idea how to call it in the MuseSDK.java file I'm creating in order to use the SDK's methods.

Answer (score 2):

To implement a .jar SDK in React Native for Android:

1. Place the .jar file in **android/app/libs.**
2. Update your **android/app/build.gradle** by adding:

```
dependencies {
    //...rest of code
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

This command includes all .jar files from the libs folder as dependencies. For a specific path, use:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'C:\\your-project-dir\\android\\app\\libs', include: ['*.aar', '*.jar'])
```

Ensure the .jar is correctly placed and sync your project after changes.